# Adding values to two lists in the exact same order

Tags: python, python-3.x

So after doing some web scraping and turning data frames into lists, I want to compare one list to another that I have created myself. But, if one list doesn’t have a value from another, I want it added in the exact order of the list I’m comparing it to.

For example, if I’m comparing one list of snacks with another

I want to make sure List2 ends up looking exactly like List1. Another thing I want to do is add the price of apples to ListPrices to “Nan” since I don’t have an existing value and I want it done in one for/if statement.

```
List1 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cookies', 'soda']
List2 = ['apples', 'cookies', 'soda']
ListPrices =  [1, 3, 1]

for i in range(List1):
    if List1[i] != List2[i]:
        List2.insert([i-1], List1[i])
        ListPrices.insert([i-1], Nan)
print(List2)
```

Above is the the python script, but I seem to be stuck at a dead end as to how to do it without generating errors. I'm hoping to get the output looking exactly like this.

```
List2 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cookies', 'soda']
ListPrices =  [1, Nan, 3, 1]
```

Any suggestions is truly appreciated.

Comment: *`for i in range(len(List1))` not `for i in range(List1)` and `insert(i-1` not `insert([i-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that prices in `ListPrices` are consistent, i.e. if `List1` has two bananas, both have the same price, you can create a `dict` by `zip`ing `List1` and `ListPrices` and then look up the price for the items in `List2` in that dict, or use `nan` as a default.

```
prices = dict(zip(List2, ListPrices))
# {'apples': 1, 'cookies': 3, 'soda': 1}

List2 = List1 # make same as List1...
ListPrices = [prices.get(x, float("nan")) for x in List1]
# [1, nan, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a dictionary for a simple look up

```
d = dict(zip(List2,ListPrices))

[d.get(i,None) for i in List1]
```

Answer (score 0):

so if I understand correctly, `ListPrices` is the list of prices for `List2`.

```
List1 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'cookies', 'soda']
List2 = ['apples', 'cookies', 'soda']
ListPrices =  [1, 3, 1]
```

If so, you can make sure to bind prices to each item of `List2` using a dict:

```
MapPrices = dict(zip(List2, ListPrices))
```

and then use that map to get the prices for `List1`:

```
>>> [MapPrices.get(item, float('NaN')) for item in List1]
[1, nan, 3, 1]
```